# Predict for wider range

Tags: r, predict, nls

I would like to fit the data and predict y values for wider x range.

Lets assume I have 'iris' data set and use following data for prediction from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376765/dplyrdo-requires-named-function)

```
 library(dplyr)
 cc <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do({
    mod <- nlsLM(Sepal.Length ~ k*Sepal.Width/2+U, start=c(k=10,U=5), data = ., trace=F, control = nls.lm.control(maxiter=100))
    pred <- predict(mod, newdata =.["Sepal.Width"])
    data.frame(., pred)
  })
```

This is the fitting plot

[image]

I want to fit this data with wider `Sepal width` range such that

```
new.range<- data.frame(x=seq(2,10,length.out=20))
```

and modify the script

```
 pred <- predict(mod, newdata =new.range)
```

TO plot new.range fitting

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cc,aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width ,col=factor(Species)))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  geom_line(aes(x=new.range,y=pred),size=1)
```

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows:
> 20, 150

I cannot understand why getting this error. I suppose that `pred` is calculated from `new.range` so they should have the same length?

similar posts

[using-predict-in-nls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721030/using-predict-in-nls)

[trouble-with-predict-function-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327490/trouble-with-predict-function-in-r)

[predict-maybe-im-not-understanding-it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028662/predict-maybe-im-not-understanding-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Do you need to call `cc$mod` instead of mod?

Comment: @troh When I tried cc$mod, `Error in predict(mod, newdata = new.range) : object 'mod' not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that achieves what you want. The cause for your original problem is that in your regression, the predictor's name is `Sepal.width` not `x`, and your prediction doesn't use your `new.range` at all, so you have to do something like `new.range<- data.frame(Sepal.Width=seq(2,10,length.out=50))` to make predictions on your `new.range`.

Another problem is that you have to make the `new.range`'s length to be 50, so that the `pred` and `new.range` fit in the original data.frame.

And then you can draw the plot you want, note that the `new.range` becomes `Sepal.Width.1`.

```
library(dplyr)
cc <- iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    do({
        mod <- nlsLM(Sepal.Length ~ k*Sepal.Width/2+U, start=c(k=10,U=5), data = ., trace=F, control = nls.lm.control(maxiter=100))
        new.range<- data.frame(Sepal.Width=seq(2,10,length.out=50))
        pred <- predict(mod, newdata =new.range)
        # pred <- predict(mod, newdata =.["Sepal.Width"])
        data.frame(., new.range, pred)

    })

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cc,aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width ,col=factor(Species)))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~Species)+
    geom_line(aes(x=Sepal.Width.1,y=pred),size=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. OTH, In my real data the length of each group is different! In the `iris` data set each species has 50 rows. Thats fine when we set length.out=50. However, in my real data there are some groups with the row size 100 or 160. So I cannot use same `length.out` parameter for them. Do you have any suggestion for that ?

Comment: @Alexander You are welcome. If the row size is different, you can replace 50 by `nrow(.)`, which should work.